# Can you think of a way that would fix a crease (created by folding) on a Razer Sphex (mousepad)?

Tags: mouse

It seems resilient enough at the point of crease. It might be better after continuous use above it (with a natural flattening) but I's wondering if anyone has a permanent active solution.

Comment: My typical solution for trying to make something flat: stick something *heavy* on it for a while. A pile of large textbooks books, maybe?

Comment: hrm. that might work, but, if it works I suspect it may need ages. It's very hard material. Or it may not work at all. I may try it.

Comment: ah.. maybe heat..

Answer (score 1):

Self - reluctant  - answer. Perhaps pressure in combination with heat.